# Set two name attribute at same input

Tags: javascript, html

I downloaded a Blogger Template and I want to collect the data through the Blogger Form Gadget to receive an email with many details about my blogger when someone contact me via that form and also I want to collect data through Google Sheets, here is what I did:

I want to add `entry.1583304807` in `name` attribute, and I do this:

```
<input class='contact-form-name contact-style' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name, entry.1583304807' placeholder='Your Name *' type='text' value=''/>
```

As you see on `name` attribute I tried to add another name by separating them using `,` and I tried also using `;` but both of them didn't work with me.

Any solution to colect the data through Blogger form and also through Google Sheets?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `name`, just like `id`, can only have one value, and cannot contain space.

Comment: @connexo so is there any trick to make this thing I wanna do works?

Answer (score 2):

Youi  can use a html5 **data-attribute** to store the meta information, such as the second name / entry content... then use JS to reference that attribute and get the assigned value. Then you can pass that value to Google sheets / Blogger etc. Here is a link to reference docs to show how to use / accesss that attribute - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```
<input 
   class='contact-form-name contact-style' 
   id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' 
   name='name'
   data-name='entry.1583304807' // this data attribute can store information about the input
   placeholder='Your Name *' 
   type='text'
   value=''
  />
```